# TypeError: Cannot read property 'authState' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, karma-jasmine

I get this error when I start my karma testing in my Angular app

Error:

`UserNavComponent should compile
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authState' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authState' of undefined
    at AuthService../src/app/auth/shared/auth.service.ts.AuthService.isAuthenticated (http://localhost:9876/src/app/auth/shared/auth.service.ts?:27:26)
    at UserNavComponent../src/app/user-nav/user-nav.component.ts.UserNavComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/src/app/user-nav/user-nav.component.ts?:28:13)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:18620:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:19884:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:19846:1)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:20480:1)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:20440:1)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/UserNavComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:20432:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:19828:1)`

The error is occurring on the components of which I subscribe to my FireAuth method called getAuthUser. This method is injected by my authService providing all the fireauth methods

Component that is failing to compile:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/shared/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-nav',
  templateUrl: './user-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-nav.component.css'],
})
export class UserNavComponent {
 showNav;
 userProfile;
 isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = 
 this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
.pipe(
  map(result => result.matches)
  );

 constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private auth: 
  AuthService) {

 }

 ngOnInit() {

    this.auth.isAuthenticated().subscribe(isAuth => {
    if(!isAuth) {
     this.showNav = false;
    }
    else
    this.showNav = true;
    })
    this.auth.getAuthUser().subscribe(authUser => {
    this.userProfile = authUser;
    })


 }


    logOut() {
    this.auth.logout();
    }


 }
```

Code of the test that is failing

Test Class:

```
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import {
MatButtonModule,
MatIconModule,
MatListModule,
MatSidenavModule,
MatToolbarModule,
} from '@angular/material';

import { UserNavComponent } from './user-nav.component';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 
'@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

describe('UserNavComponent', () => {
let component: UserNavComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserNavComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [UserNavComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: AngularFirestore} ,{ provide: AngularFireAuth}, 
{provide: AngularFirestoreDocument}],
  imports: [
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    ]
    }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserNavComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should compile', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
    });
```

Expecting it to compile, but it fails to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to mock your services?  If so, you’ll want to set up a mock first, then substitute your mock for the service in the providers array.  For example, instead of { provide: AngularFireAuth }, it would be something like { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: angularFireAuthSpy }

Comment: I am not trying to mock the authservice, I am trying to make my test pass for compiling my components, I don't find any other return observable method problematic in that attempt, so I am pundering as to why this exact observable causes the same problem in my 3 component cases. If mocking is the way to go, how come I did not have to mock any other method returning an observable value?

Comment: Please replace the links to images of code with the actual code itself.

Comment: Why mock is a good question.  There are many good answers out there, here is one in the middle of a fairly lengthy article: [Why Mock](https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angular-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-1#toc-why-mock-).  As for why your other tests worked, that is the nature of asynchronous code - sometimes it is fast enough to complete in time, sometimes it is still undefined.

Comment: But am I not assuring synchronous code with the observable that I wrote in my component code? Is the test ignoring my subscription for some reason?